# Allegro 5 multiple files in project

Tags: c++, allegro5

I'm making Allegro 5 project divided for several files, but I can't compile it.

In .hpp file i have class declaration in which I use "ALLEGRO_BITMAP" type, but compiler says that "'ALLEGO_BITMAP' does not name a type", despite I included the same fils which are enough to compile and run that project when everything is in one file, I mean :

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"
```

So currently I have only two files (for testing):
"main.cpp" - with the same including as above + with

```
#include "header_file.hpp"
```

and with all allegro initializing (al_init(), al_init_image_addon() etc.)

"header_file.hpp":

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE_HPP
#define HEADER_FILE_HPP

#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"

class testing_class
{
    ALLEGO_BITMAP *bitmap;

};

#endif
```

When I delete

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
```

line in .hpp file I have more errors:

> allegro_image.h|32|error: 'al_init_image_addon' has not been declared|
>   allegro_image.h|32|error: expected identifier before '(' token|
>   allegro_image.h|32|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token|
>   allegro_image.h|33|error: 'al_shutdown_image_addon' has not been declared|
>   allegro_image.h|33|error: expected identifier before '(' token|
>   allegro_image.h|33|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token|
>   allegro_image.h|34|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token|
>   header_file.hpp|74|error: 'ALLEGO_BITMAP' does not name a type|

I tried to make that "bitmap" variable extern and declare it in "main.cpp" but that doesn't solved the problem.

I wanted to ask in allegro.cc forum, but despite I received registration e-mail I can't log in with those initial login information.

Comment: Did you call all the al_init() functions? Is the class being instanced BEFORE those calls? Read the image add-on tutorial on the allegro wiki, probably you are missing something...

Comment: I have asked many people and no one saw that I made typo in "ALLEGO_BITMAP" :P In spite of all thank you for your attention. Topic may be closed :)

Comment: Wow, those are the hard ones to catch... Has happened to everyone here at least one time, nice catch!